# Polymer 1, the changes in myObject in the child component are not reflected in the parent component

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

**Description:**

hola-mundo is a parent component,
hola-mundo2 is a child component,
MyObject is shared by two-databinding between the two components, when we press the button "changeValueMyObject" the value object "MyObject" is changed in the child component. but in the father component the object "My Object" isn't changed.

**Steps to reproduce the error:**

1.-Press button "changeValueMyObject"  (this change the value in the child component)

2.-Press button "showValueMyObject" (this show the MyObject value in the parent component)

**Behaviour expected:**

{id: 1, name: "Barcelona"} is displayed in the console.

**Actual behaviour:**

undefined is displayed in the console

Can someone correct my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Prueba de index</title>
 <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
 <link rel="import" href="./hola-mundo.html">
</header>
<body>

 <hola-mundo></hola-mundo>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./hidding-behaviour.html">
<link rel="import" href="./hola-mundo2.html">
<dom-module id="hola-mundo">
 <style>
  h1{
   color: blue;
  }
 </style>
 <template>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  
  <button on-click="showValueMyobject">showValueMyobject</button>
  <hola-mundo2 myObject={{myObject}}></hola-mundo2>
 </template>

 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "hola-mundo",  
   properties:{
    myObject: {
     type: Object,
     notify: true,
     observer: "projectChanged"    
    },
   },

   changeValueMyObject: function(){
    let obj ={
     id:2,
     name:'Madrid'
    }
    this.set('myObject',obj)
   }, 
   
   showValueMyobject: function(){
    debugger
    console.log(this.myObject);
   }, 
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

```html
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./hidding-behaviour.html">
<dom-module id="hola-mundo2">
 <style>
  h1{
   color: blue;
  }
 </style>
 <template>
  <h1>hello world2</h1>
  <button on-click="changeValueMyObject">changeValueMyObject2</button>
  
  
 </template>

 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "hola-mundo2",   
   properties:{
    myObject: {
     type: Object,
     notify: true
     
    },
   },
   
   changeValueMyObject: function(){
    let obj ={
     id:1,
     name:'Barcelona'
    }
    this.set('myObject', obj);
   }, 
   
   showValueMyobject: function(){
    debugger
    console.log(this.myObject);
   }, 
   
  });
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: The code and Polymer thinking looks correct. You missed " around {{myObject}} in `<hola-mundo2 myObject={{myObject}}></hola-mundo2>`. What happens when you add an observer to `myObject` in `hola-mundo2` so `showValueMyobject` displays it when `myObject` changes?

Comment: Hi Rickard Elimää, thanks for you reponse. The error was in: <hola-mundo2 myObject={{myObject}}></hola-mundo2> The correct will be:<hola-mundo2 my-object={{myObject}}></hola-mundo2>